# Unable to get the spring context.getBean() from <util:properties>

Tags: java, spring, properties

I created an spring xml config file with

```
<util:properties
  id="com.abc.xyz.handler.abchandler"
  location="classpath:/properties/myhandler_${spring.profile.active:e3}.properties" />
```

now from my java program when I am trying to get the property file like below:

```
Properties props = ((Properties).getBean(getClass().getName()));
```

it is saying NO bean with the name com.abc.xyz.handler.abchandler has been defined.

Please help !!

Comment: <util:properties
  id="com.abc.xyz.handler.abc"
  location="classpath:/properties/myhandler_${spring.profile.active}.properties" /> and from my java class trying to load the properties like below

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that in the first place... that is what dependency injection is for...

Answer (score 1):

From your supplied code you are using getBean() but you have not passed in the properties file. Moreover, you have not declared the properties file as a bean in the  spring-xml config file.

You could try accessing the properties file in this way:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("nameOfYourPropertiesFile.properties");
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```